# Adding item from database to inventory not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made c# database (In memory list of objects), which code then injects on startup into Unity inspector.

After that I have made a script which should add item to your inventory. For some reason, this code works in 1 of my scripts, in which it automatically adds 3 items to inventory in `void Start()`.

But it doesn't want to work on `buttonClick` function (it works fine where it has to add item). I believe that it has something to do with inventory size, which is let's say now 3.

I don't know if I have to manualy add slot to invetory when I inject item with `inventory.Add(database.Items[16]);`

My scripts are this:

```
public class crateOpener : MonoBehaviour
{
    float money;
    float wandererCrateValue = 0.60f;
    float pioneerCrateValue = 1.15f;
    float gamescomCrateValue = 1.91f;
    float survivorCrateValue = 0.64f;

    public List<Item> inventory = new List<Item>();
    public List<Item> slots = new List<Item>();
    private ItemDatabase database;

    public Text moneyText;

    public void openCrate(string crateName)
    {
        database = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Item Database").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();

        double doubleMoney = Convert.ToDouble(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("money.txt"));
        float money = ToSingle(doubleMoney);

        if (crateName == "Wanderer")
        {
            if (money < wandererCrateValue)
            {
                Debug.Log("You don't have enough moeny!");
            }
            else
            {
                openWandererCrate();
                money -= wandererCrateValue;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText("money.txt", money.ToString());
                moneyText.text = money.ToString() + "$";
                inventory.Add(database.Items[1]);
                inventory.Add(database.Items[2]);
                Debug.Log("You opened Wanerer Crate");
                Debug.Log("Money left: " + money);
            }
        }
        else if (crateName == "Pioneer")
        {
            if (money < pioneerCrateValue)
            {
                Debug.Log("You don't have enough moeny!");
            }
            else
            {
                openPioneerCrate();
                money -= pioneerCrateValue;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText("money.txt", money.ToString());
                moneyText.text = money.ToString() + "$";
                Debug.Log("You opened Wanerer Crate");
                Debug.Log("Money left: " + money);
            }
        }
        else if (crateName == "Gamescom")
        {
            if (money < gamescomCrateValue)
            {
                Debug.Log("You don't have enough moeny!");
            }
            else
            {
                openGamescomCrate();
                money -= gamescomCrateValue;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText("money.txt", money.ToString());
                moneyText.text = money.ToString() + "$";
                Debug.Log("You opened Wanerer Crate");
                Debug.Log("Money left: " + money);
            }
        }
        else if (crateName == "Survivor")
        {
            if (money < survivorCrateValue)
            {
                Debug.Log("You don't have enough moeny!");
            }
            else
            {
                openSurvivorCrate();
                money -= survivorCrateValue;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText("money.txt", money.ToString());
                moneyText.text = money.ToString() + "$";
                Debug.Log("You opened Wanerer Crate");
                Debug.Log("Money left: " + money);
            }
        }
    }

    void openWandererCrate()
    {
        database = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Item Database").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();
        //addMoney(wandererCrateValue);
    }

    void openPioneerCrate()
    {
        database = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Item Database").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();
        //addMoney(pioneerCrateValue);
    }

    void openGamescomCrate()
    {
        database = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Item Database").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();
        //addMoney(gamescomCrateValue);
    }

    void openSurvivorCrate()
    {
        database = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Item Database").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();
        //addMoney(survivorCrateValue);
    }

    public static float DoubleToFloat(double dValue)
    {
        if (float.IsPositiveInfinity(Convert.ToSingle(dValue)))
        {
            return float.MaxValue;
        }
        if (float.IsNegativeInfinity(Convert.ToSingle(dValue)))
        {
            return float.MinValue;
        }
        return Convert.ToSingle(dValue);
    }

    public static float ToSingle(double value)
    {
        return (float)value;
    }
}
```

And this is database

```
public class ItemDatabase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();

    //Edit missing ItemType3 colors... Or wrong colors... And add missing colors to database...

    void Start()
    {
        //Wanderer Crate
        Items.Add(new Item("Bloody Combat Pants", 0, 0.12f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Blue Hi-top Trainers", 1, 2.12f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shoes, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Boots (Punk)", 2, 0.19f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shoes, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Cargo Pants (Beige)", 3, 0.19f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Cargo Pants (Blue)", 4, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Cargo Pants (Khaki)", 5, 0.06f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Dirty Tank-top (White)", 6, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Floral Shirt", 7, 10.19f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Glasses (Punk)", 8, 0.37f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Glasses, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Hotpants (Blue)", 9, 138.12f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Long Sleeved T-shirt (Striped)", 10, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Long-sleeved T-shirt (Black)", 11, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Long-sleeved T-shirt (Light Blue)", 12, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Mandarin Jacket (Blue)", 13, 18.60f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Jacket, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Padded Jacket(Urban)", 14, 1.77f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Jacket, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Pleated Mini-skirt (Blue)", 15, 170.97f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Ballistic Mask", 16, 19.02f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Mask, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Protective Glasses", 17, 45.43f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Glasses, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("School Shirt (Open)", 18, 17.14f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("School Shoes", 19, 17.14f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shoes, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Working Boots", 20, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shoes, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Slacks (Blue)", 21, 4.20f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Pants, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("T-shirt (Red)", 22, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("T-shirt (Striped)", 23, 0.04f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
        Items.Add(new Item("Tank - top(Charcoal)", 24, 0.09f, Item.ItemType1.Wanderer_Crate, Item.ItemType2.Shirt, Item.ItemType3.Blue));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of not working ? Any error? What unexpected behavior you are seeing?

Comment: I'm not seeing any code that handles a button click.

Comment: It doesn't add it at all... Button works, I have it set on onClick(), btw I tried Debug.Log() and it printed line, that I wrote, so button is working, it's just that it doesn't add list item to Inventory at all...

Comment: Is the openCrate function called from the ButtonClick event?

Comment: Yeah and then I have that string crate name, where I type name and it goes for if statement... Everything works like I said, literally just add item doesn't work, if I do Debug.Log("Test") right after add item, it is gonna put out to log, just the part of add doesn't work